# Vertx.io - how to get count of requests made on a single http connection?

Tags: node.js, vert.x

For statistics purposes I want to count how many requests are made on a single Http Connection (how many keep-alive requests are made on one open socket).

In node.js I have access to 'socket' in request and response object and I can dynamically add a field, for example 'requests' and increment it. I can also attach 'socket close' handler and then log 'request' field into syslog and get the 1 min average in Graphite.

Is this possible with vertx.io? I cant find socket field in HttpRequest and HttpResponse classes.

Answer (score 2):

There's no straightforward way to do this.

You might do a hack: `HttpServerRequest` is actually an instance of `org.vertx.java.core.http.impl.DefaultHttpServerRequest` that has private field `ServerConnection conn`. This field can be accessed via reflection, as described for example here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html. Request counting might be implemented by creating a map of connections to integers.

This hack is good enough for testing purposes, but I won't work on production because of memory leaks. It would be better to add this functionality into `handleMessage` method of `ServerConnection` class and expose it via JMX.